# Get a word in textarea with a line down using cgi python

Tags: python, html, cgi, cgi-bin

how to get a word in the textarea on the form , and sort it down?
EX:

Input : 
tes1, tes2, tes3

result: 
tes1
tes2
 
tes3

HTML

```
<form action="http://localhost/getword.py" method="post" >
<textarea name="textcontent" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

CGI Py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb 

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

if form.getlist('textcontent'):
   text_content = form.getvalue('textcontent').replace(',','\n')
else:
   text_content = "Not entered"

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>";
print "<title>Text Area - Fifth CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>%s</h2>" % text_content
print "</body>"
```